# Updating CCNET Last Build Label from an assembly version

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, version, label, revision, .net-assembly

I Have managed to create a CI project that uses GIT as it's source control, and an MSBuild extension to label the assemblies based on the CCNet build label, and commit that changed label

I have other projects that are manually triggered to publish this version to particular sites etc.

I would like the project status in the dashboard to display the build label (eg 2.1.345.0) from the assembly, or from a built dll, so that we can easily see which revision was published at the last manual trigger.

There's plentyof info on updating assembly info for a build, but nothing on using a assemby ifnfo version for the displayed 'last build label'

Any Ideas anybody ? Do I need to create a task to manually update the state file ? that sounds a bit dodgy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

None of the built-in labellers does what you need, but you should probably be able to write your own custom labeller to that.

You can find two custom labellers with source code [here](http://nimtug.org/blogs/simon/pages/CCNet-MS-Project-Labeller.aspx) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/svnrevisionlabeller/) to get you started.